# Using a controller for a simple heating system

Tags: control-engineering, modeling, simulink

I am new to control modeling. Given the following problem: I want to control the heating of a house. Therefore, a top unit should be switched on (nominal load, no ramp up) as soon as the production of the main unit is above a certain level. How would you do this? Is it possible to set the output of a p-controller to a fixed value?

```
if main_unit < level:
  top_unit = 0
else:
  top_unit = nominal_load
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a proportional control. The type of controller you describe (switching from 0 to full load and back to 0 almost instantaneously) is called a [bang-bang controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang%E2%80%93bang_control). This controller is often used as a simplified model of a furnace heating system in a house, which can only be on or off. It is important to include a dead band (a range where the control stays on if it's currently on and off if it's currently off) into this type of controller to prevent high frequency switching near the setpoint.

Since your question is tagged with Simulink, I would suggest looking into the 'Relay' block as a way of implementing this type of controller.